# File Downloading in Struts 2 won't start

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, download, struts2

I've the following struts code. I'm trying to download a csv file but nothing happens when I click download. I don't get any errors and in javascript I get a successful response. Myy post function logs my csv content on browser console too. I can't see why the file download won't start downloading.

**Here is my jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<div>
    <div>


    <h4>Information</h4>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="login">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <form id = "info" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div >
                            <label>FName</label>
                            <span style="float:right"><s:property value="%{fName}" 
     </span>

                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>MName or Initial</label>
                            <span style="float:right"><s:property value="%{mName}"/></span>

                        </div>  
                        <div>
                            <label>LName</label>
                            <span style="float:right"><s:property value="%{lName}"/></span>

                        </div>  
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="download();">Download</button>          
            </div>
    </div>



    <script>
    function download(){
        var action = 'download.action';
        var meth = 'post';
        var fields = jQuery("#info").children();
        var params = [];
        for(var i=0; i<fields.length;i++){
            var field = fields[i];
            var nodes = jQuery(field).children();
            if(nodes.length == 2){
                params.push(encodeURIComponent(nodes[0].innerText)
                        +"="+
                        encodeURIComponent(nodes[1].innerText)); 
            }
        }
        var encr = btoa(params.join('&'));
        jQuery.post(action,"data="+encr,function(data,status,xhr){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(xhr);
        });

    }
    </script>
```

**Action class**

```
public class Downloads extends CustomActionClass{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private String data;
   private InputStream fileStream;
   private long contentLength;


    public String execute() {
        String decodeData = new 
        String(java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(data));
    List<String> downloadData = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
             String fileName = "info.csv";
        String [] dataList = URLDecoder.decode(decodeData,"UTF-8").split("&");
             String header ="";
                 String vals = "";
                 for(String dat: dataList) {
                     String[] tData = dat.split("=");
                     header += tData[0] + ",";
                     if(tData.length>1)
                         vals += tData[1]+",";
                 }

                 if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(header))
                     downloadData.add(header.substring(0,header.length()-1));
                 if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(vals))
                     downloadData.add(vals.substring(0,vals.length()-1));

                 File fil = new File(getServerTempFolder()+fileName);
                 fil.createNewFile();
                 contentLength = fil.length();
                 FileUtils.writeLines(fil, "UTF-8", downloadData);
                 fileStream =  new FileInputStream(fil);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                log.debug(e.fillInStackTrace());
            }       
    return SUCCESS;
}

        /**
         * @return the data
         */
        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

        /**
         * @param data the data to set
         */
        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        /**
         * @return the fileStream
         */
        public InputStream getFileStream() {
            return fileStream;
        }

        /**
         * @param fileStream the fileStream to set
         */
        public void setFileStream(InputStream fileStream) {
            this.fileStream = fileStream;
        }

        /**
         * @return the contentLength
         */
        public long getContentLength() {
            return contentLength;
        }

        /**
         * @param contentLength the contentLength to set
         */
        public void setContentLength(long contentLength) {
            this.contentLength = contentLength;
        }

    }
```

Here is my Struts Mapping:

```
<action name="download" class="com.util.Downloads">
<result name="success" type="stream">
<param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
<param name="contentLength">${contentLength}</param>
<param name="inputName">fileStream</param>
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="info.csv"</param>
<param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
```

Comment: What does the JavaScript function do?

Comment: The javascript function creates params and ecrypt them and after that ajax call posts them to class.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. So the solution to this is that ajax call won't trigger the download since it's a *post request*. I had to do `window.href=action;` this made the get call and hence the stream was returned from the action class.

I'm going to go one step further in case anyone has encoding issues. To encode properly for pdf write correct headers to specify UTF-8 encoding.. for csv write this to file `byte[] enc = new byte[] { (byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF };` before you start write your data to file. And yes you can write this byte stream and then write String data to file.

Refer to this link for CSV http://smallbusiness.chron.com/utf8-encoding-excel-using-java-47939.html ...